# How to get a triangle on the edge of a line

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Sorry if my title was confusing. I am wanting to design a rectangle and on one of the sides I want the tip of a triangle to come out of the rectangle. Like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: They are called tooltips. Give it a search on google

Comment: http://www.cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bhccpnjn/

Comment: Thanks Anonymous and Dhaval! That is perfect.